# xcode error library not found for -lassimp

Tags: c++, xcode5, assimp

I used the method described in the answer of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922738/2197292
to build Assimp 3.0 on my Mac OS X 10.9. I use Xcode 5.0.2. Then I added libassimp.a to frameworks and added /usr/local/include/assimp to header search paths. Am I missing something? When I build my project I get this error:

```
Ld DerivedData/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/Build/Products/Debug/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp normal x86_64
cd /Users/MATH/Documents/XCODE/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/MATH/Documents/XCODE/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/DerivedData/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/MATH/Documents/XCODE/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/DerivedData/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/MATH/Documents/XCODE/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/DerivedData/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/Build/Intermediates/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp.build/Debug/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lassimp -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/MATH/Documents/XCODE/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/DerivedData/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/Build/Intermediates/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp.build/Debug/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/MATH/Documents/XCODE/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/DerivedData/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp/Build/Products/Debug/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenGLGLSL5Assimp

ld: library not found for -lassimp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```