# AssImp library problems on CDT eclipse OS X 10.6.8 : unsupported file format for architecture i386

Tags: opengl, eclipse-cdt, i386, assimp

I have been trying to link the very useful AssImp-library in my OpenGl project in Eclipse (CDT)

I successfully installed the AssImp library by following the answer to this question:

[Trouble building the Open Asset Import Library (Assimp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594315/trouble-building-the-open-asset-import-library-assimp)

I also successfully set up OpenGl in Eclipse(CDT) by following the answer to this question:

[OpenGL and GLUT in Eclipse on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068693/opengl-and-glut-in-eclipse-on-os-x)

Now when i try to build some code where the AssImp-lib is being used the following error appears:

ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libassimp.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

I guess the library is built for the wrong architecture ... 
I tried filling in "i386"in the CMake's "CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES:" flag but this does not help in any way...

---

Ok I changed the architecture but it still gives some linking errors..

does anybody have the same errors ?

Undefined symbols:
  "_get_crc_table", referenced from:
      _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in libassimp.a(unzip.c.o)
  "*inflateInit2*", referenced from:
      Assimp::XGLImporter::InternReadFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, aiScene*, Assimp::IOSystem*)in libassimp.a(XGLLoader.cpp.o)
      Assimp::BlenderImporter::InternReadFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, aiScene*, Assimp::IOSystem*)in libassimp.a(BlenderLoader.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      _unzOpenCurrentFile3 in libassimp.a(unzip.c.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      Assimp::XGLImporter::InternReadFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, aiScene*, Assimp::IOSystem*)in libassimp.a(XGLLoader.cpp.o)
      Assimp::BlenderImporter::InternReadFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, aiScene*, Assimp::IOSystem*)in libassimp.a(BlenderLoader.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      _unzCloseCurrentFile in libassimp.a(unzip.c.o)
  "_inflateSetDictionary", referenced from:
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      Assimp::XGLImporter::InternReadFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, aiScene*, Assimp::IOSystem*)in libassimp.a(XGLLoader.cpp.o)
      Assimp::BlenderImporter::InternReadFile(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, aiScene*, Assimp::IOSystem*)in libassimp.a(BlenderLoader.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      _unzReadCurrentFile in libassimp.a(unzip.c.o)
  "_crc32", referenced from:
      _unzReadCurrentFile in libassimp.a(unzip.c.o)
      _unzReadCurrentFile in libassimp.a(unzip.c.o)
  "_inflateReset", referenced from:
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
      Assimp::XFileParser::XFileParser(std::vector > const&)in libassimp.a(XFileParser.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found

Comment: Sounds like a rather round-about way for Clang (presumably on OS X) to complain that `assimp` is x86_64. Change your build architecture to x86_64 and this should go away.

Comment: thank u for your answer! , but could u please be more specific ? I changed the C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Linker -> Miscellaneous linker flag to -arch x86_64 but this didn't work. thanx

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding the zlib library in the linker libraries -> add "z"

as suggested by gabor papp in the assimp-mailinglist